# Angular wait for method to finish

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous

I have HTTP interceptor that intercepts http requests for api

First it check's is this api that requires authorization, after that checks for session variables to see is there token saved already and checks is it valid

If there is no token or token is expired, it should get new token and then carry on as usual

The rest of code gets executed before token is retrieved, and then it doesn't add required auth header.  I don't know how to make it wait.

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    let authReq = request;
    const token = this.checkUrl(authReq.url)
    if (token){
      authReq = request.clone({ 
        headers: request.headers.set(this.TOKEN_HEADER_KEY, 'Bearer ' + token) 
      });
    }
    return next.handle(authReq);
  }
```

`checkUrl` method that gets token and checks if auth is required

```
checkUrl(url: string): string {
    if (url.includes('/login')){
      return ''
    }
    for (let x of this.includedList) {
      if (url.includes(x.url)){
        return this.auth.getApiToken()
        //break;
      }
    }
    return ''
  }
```

`getApiToken` method that gets token from session storage or from login endpoint

```
getApiToken(): string{
    let token = <string>sessionStorage.getItem('auth-token');
    if (!token || this.jwt.isTokenExpired(token)){
      this.apiLogin().subscribe({
        next: data => {
          console.log(data)
          sessionStorage.setItem("auth-token", data.token)
          token = data.token
        },
        error: err => {
          console.log(err)
          token = ''
        }
      })
    } 
    return token;
  }
```

And finally `apiLogin` method that gets new token from api

```
apiLogin(): Observable<any> {
    const loginData = {
      username: environment.apiLoginData.username,
      password: environment.apiLoginData.password
    }
    return this.http.post(AUTH_API, loginData);
  }
```

EDIT

Solution I tried with Observable and map

`interceptor`

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    let authReq = request;
    let token = ''
    this.checkUrlV2(authReq.url).pipe(map(data => {
      console.log(data)
      token = data
    }));
    console.log('token')
    console.log(token)
    if (token){
      authReq = request.clone({ 
        headers: request.headers.set(this.TOKEN_HEADER_KEY, 'Bearer ' + token) 
      });
    }
    return next.handle(authReq);
  }
```

`checkUrlV2`

```
checkUrlV2(url: string): Observable<string> {
    if (url.includes('/login')){
      return of('')
    }
    for (let x of this.includedList) {
      if (url.includes(x.url)){
        this.auth.apiTokenV2().pipe(map(data => {
          console.log(data)
          return of(data)
        }));
        //break;
      }
    }
    return of('')
  }
```

`apiTokenV2`

```
apiTokenV2() {
    let token = ''
    if (!token || this.jwt.isTokenExpired(token)){
      this.apiLogin().pipe(map(data => {
        console.log(data)
        sessionStorage.setItem("auth-token", data.token)
        return of(data.token)
      }));
    }
    return of(token)
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular HttpInterceptor - Handle with async response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748462/angular-httpinterceptor-handle-with-async-response)

Comment: Hi, I don't see how I can use same solution. That is doing something on response, not request, and it does it every time, in every solution I have tried problem for me was that I have to do all that for only certain requests. I will edit original post, adding one example I tried with map and Observable but still didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution that works for my case. It does request without checking token, then refreshes it if it gets error

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    req = this.addAuthenticationToken(req);

    return <Observable<HttpEvent<any>>>next.handle(req).pipe(
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (error && error.status === 401) {
          if (this.refreshTokenInProgress) {
            // If refreshTokenInProgress is true, we will wait until refreshTokenSubject has a non-null value which means the new token is ready and we can retry the request again
            return this.refreshTokenSubject.pipe(
              filter(result => result !== null),
              take(1),
              switchMap(() => next.handle(this.addAuthenticationToken(req)))
            );
          } else {
            this.refreshTokenInProgress = true;
            // Set the refreshTokenSubject to null so that subsequent API calls will wait until the new token has been retrieved
            this.refreshTokenSubject.next(null);
            
            return this.refreshAccessToken().pipe(
              switchMap((success: boolean) => {               
                this.refreshTokenSubject.next(success);
                return next.handle(this.addAuthenticationToken(req));
              }),
              // When the call to refreshToken completes we reset the refreshTokenInProgress to false for the next time the token needs to be refreshed
              finalize(() => this.refreshTokenInProgress = false)
            );
          }
        } else {
          return throwError(() => new Error(error.message));
        }
      })
    );
  }

  private refreshAccessToken(): Observable<any> {
    return this.auth.apiLogin().pipe(map(authData => {
      console.log('Token refreshed')
      sessionStorage.setItem("auth-token", authData.token)
      return authData.token
    }))
  }
  private addAuthenticationToken(request: HttpRequest<any>): HttpRequest<any> {
    const token = <string>sessionStorage.getItem('auth-token')
    for (let x of this.excludedUrl){
      if (request.url.includes(x)){
        return request;
      }
    }
    for (let x of this.includedList) {
      if (request.url.includes(x.url)){
        console.log('Bearer token added')
        return request.clone({
          headers: request.headers.set(this.TOKEN_HEADER_KEY, 'Bearer ' + token) 
        });
      }
    }
    return request;
  }
```